# Slurm Error: “If using PrologFlag=Contain for pam_slurm_adopt, either proctrack/cgroup or proctrack/crau_aries is required.”

Tags: x11, slurm

I'm using the flag x11 (`PrologFlags=x11`) in my `slurm.conf` file and jobs with x11 works perfectly, but I am getting this error every time I run a slurm command (e.g. `sbatch, srun, sacctmgr`):

`scontrol: error: If using PrologFlag=Contain for pam_slurm_adopt, either proctrack/cgroup or proctrack/crau_aries is required. If not using pam_slurm_adopt, please ignore error.`

How can I hide it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Not even uninstalling `pam_slurm_adopt` removed this error...